# When I plug in a phone with pictures, it does not appear in the files application

Tags: 20.10

When I plug in a phone with pictures, it does not appear in the files application. I do NOT know what to do. Can you help? My version of ubuntu is 20.10. I want some answer now!

Comment: 1 is this a clean install of 20.10 or did you update from 20.04?(could be a bad update it's best to do a clean install) 2 is this a laptop or desktop computer? (could be a hardware issue) 3 did you enable the function on your phone (I know stupid question but the more info we have the better we can help you)

Comment: I updated from 20.04 and it's a laptop and I do not know what you mean by "function".

Comment: I mean if you have an android phone when you plug it into your computer it will ask you if you want to allow access to the phones data if you don't accept you will not be able to access the phones files

Answer (score 2):

Have not installed in 20.10, although I have it. I use 20.04 as main working install. I typically install these, but still manually mount & pair.

```
apt-get install ideviceinstaller python-imobiledevice libimobiledevice-utils python-plist usbmuxd

sudo mkdir /mnt/iPhone
sudo chown  $USER:$USER /mnt/iPhone 
sudo chmod  a+rwX,o-w /mnt/iPhone

idevicepair pair
ifuse /mnt/iPhone/

to unmount:
fusermount -u /mnt/iPhone
idevicepair unpair
```

And then drill down from / into /mnt and then /mnt/iPhone folder. You could mount to /home, /media, or anyplace you prefer.

Comment: My iPhone works without any additional installs. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

For an old Samsung Galaxy SIII the following works:
Install the Media Transfer Protocol runtime:

```
sudo apt-get install libmtp9 libmtp-runtime libmtp-common
```

Then when the phone is attached via USB, the phone might decide to attach as a camera instead of media storage.  One way is to click on the phone notification (usb attached as a camera), and change it to storage.  Then if there is still a problem, like the phone showing up in Files, but not being able to attach, briefly detach and reattach the usb cable.  The reattachment should stay media, and you should be able to navigate the phone to where the pictures are stored (e.g. storage card, DCIM, camera, etc.).